# how to get total and used heap memory of a process in java programatically

Tags: java, jconsole, jmap

How to get total and used heap memory of a process in java?

```
    strong textint mb = 1024 * 1024;
    Runtime instance = Runtime.getRuntime();
    System.out.println("***** Heap utilization statistics [MB] *****\n");
    System.out.println("Total Memory: " + instance.totalMemory() / mb);
    String str = "9280";
    Process pr = instance.exec("cmd /c jmap -heap "+str);
```

This is Windows based, I need it for cross platform.

Comment: you can put the last line in the if loop under condition `System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")`

Comment: again i need to do the same for Linux again for Solaris . can there be a generic solution which i can use for all the platform.

Comment: You want to trigger a "heap dump"? You may call the HotSpot VM Bean and trigger the heap dump method. Or the "MemoryMXBean" class for information only.

Comment: using "MemoryMXBean" we can calculate JVM heap memory but i want to calculate the total and used memory of a current running process assuming i have Process id.